# Is this out-of-bounds warning from gcc erroneous?

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc-warning

Earlier today, gcc gave me a warning that I belive to be erroneous and now I am very unsure if it is an actual compiler bug(usually highly unlikely) or a bug in my code(usually highly likely). I managed to reduce it down to the following code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::array<int,8> test{};
    int valid = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<8;++i)
    {
        if(i==0)
            test[valid++] = 0;
    }
    
//    if(valid<8)
        std::sort(test.begin(),test.begin()+valid);
}
```

[Here it is on Compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/fc57MYscf)

When compiled with optimization level -O2 or higher with gcc 12.1 or trunk, this warning about an out-of-bounds access is emitted:

```
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.1.0/include/c++/12.1.0/algorithm:61,
                 from <source>:1:
In function 'void std::__final_insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = int*; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]',
    inlined from 'void std::__final_insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = int*; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]' at /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.1.0/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_algo.h:1844:5,
    inlined from 'void std::__sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = int*; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]' at /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.1.0/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_algo.h:1940:31,
    inlined from 'void std::__sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = int*; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]' at /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.1.0/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_algo.h:1932:5,
    inlined from 'void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter) [with _RAIter = int*]' at /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.1.0/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_algo.h:4820:18,
    inlined from 'int main()' at <source>:16:15:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.1.0/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_algo.h:1849:32: error: array subscript 16 is outside array bounds of 'std::array<int, 8> [1]' [-Werror=array-bounds]
 1849 |           std::__insertion_sort(__first, __first + int(_S_threshold), __comp);
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:7:27: note: at offset 64 into object 'test' of size 32
    7 |         std::array<int,8> test{};
```

I believe that to be mistaken. According to my limited understanding, valid is only incremented once and will always be 1.

Even if the condition were replaced with some unpredictable function call, in the worst case it would be true every time, yielding valid==8 at the end of the loop, which should still be alright?

Additionally, I have thus far made the following observations:

- The warning is not produced at lower optimization levels, on gcc <=11 or on clang.
- Interestingly, the warning is also not produce with array sizes >8 or <6, only for sizes 6,7, and 8.
- When I remove the condition inside the loop body(the "if(i==0)", to increment every time and always yield valid==8), the warning disappears.
- When I add the condition before the sort call(and thereby provide the compiler with an additional hint about the limits of valid), the warning disappears.

Especially the latter two make me believe I might have managed to confuse gcc's analysis somehow, but also make me question if I am overlooking something obvious or managed to introduce some subtle undefined behaviour in my code.

Am I misunderstanding something in my sleep deprived state or did I encounter a genuine, mostly harmless, compiler bug?

Comment: You can congratulate yourself on finding a compiler bug. Been there, done that.

Comment: Note that if `valid==8` you still have an out-of-bounds access, since `test[8]` is one past the end.

Comment: This warning is very often wrong (see the links in https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56456).

Comment: @NathanPierson I don't access test[8], I pass test.begin()+8 to sort as the end of the range, which - if I understand correctly - may be one past the end(and has to be to cover the whole array)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I apologize if the question came across as self-congratulatory in any way, that was not my intention. I merely wanted to make sure I don't miss anything here. Is the question inappropriate for stackoverflow?

Comment: I don't think Sam meant his comment in a bad way. This question is ok on SO, there are many similar questions here. It isn't the most interesting kind of question for readers though, all we can say is "yes, bug". Note however that SO is not the right place to report a bug, bugs should be reported to the bug tracker of whatever project has the bug (gcc in this case).

Comment: @MarcGlisse Thank you for the clarification! Thanks to your link above, I found a comment in one of the bug reports that contains almost the exact same code as I posted above and thereby answers my question (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=104165). 
What is the correct behaviour on here in that case? Answering my own question and accepting it seems disingenuous, as it was really you who answered in a comment

Comment: Self-answering is perfectly fine, go ahead (and do include this bugzilla link in your answer).

Comment: @PhilippLenk Yes you're correct, that was a misunderstanding on my part

Comment: I'll confirm that -- I'd much rather read a question of this kind than 90% of the garbage that gets posted every day here. Even if there isn't much to say -- yes it's a compiler bug, it's quite interesting to see how compilers get it wrong and speculate on the possible reasons. I have my own bug open for gcc where it also complains about perfectly fine code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed a compiler bug, as can be seen [in this bugzilla report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=104165), which contains almost identical code to the one in my question.

Thanks to Marc Glisse for providing [this link to a lot of similar bugs](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56456) and thereby helping me track down the relevant one.